# Is there a way to force lxml to parse Unicode strings that specify an encoding in a tag?

Tags: python, lxml

I have an XML file that specifies an encoding, and I use UnicodeDammit to convert it to unicode (for reasons of storage, I can't store it as a string). I later pass it to lxml but it refuses to ignore the encoding specified in the file and parse it as Unicode, and it raises an exception.

How can I force lxml to parse the document? This behaviour seems too restrictive.

Answer (score 22):

You cannot parse from unicode strings AND have an encoding declaration in the string.
So, either you make it an encoded string (as you apparently can't store it as a string, you will have to re-encode it before parsing. Or you serialize the tree as unicode with lxml yourself: `etree.tostring(tree, encoding=unicode)`, WITHOUT xml declaration. You can easily parse the result again with etree.fromunicode

see http://lxml.de/parsing.html#python-unicode-strings

Edit: If, apparently, you already have the unicode string, and can't control how that was made. You'll have to encode it again, and provide the parser with the encoding you used:

```
utf8_parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')

def parse_from_unicode(unicode_str):
    s = unicode_str.encode('utf-8')
    return etree.fromstring(s, parser=utf8_parser)
```

This will make sure that, whatever was inside the xml declaration gets ignored, because the parser will always use utf-8.

Comment: The whole problem is that I can't get a tree in the first place, if I could I wouldn't have any problems...

Comment: @Stavros Korokithakis, etree is module, not the parsed tree.

Comment: @Daniel Kluev: Yes, but "tree" is a tree.

Comment: @Steven: Regarding your edit, that should work, thanks. In the end, I took the encoding detection regex from lxml and used it to strip the encoding from the file. Since it fails early, I think it should be the fastest.

Comment: This solution is wrong. Don't blindly encode to utf8. The encoding declaration inside the document could very well be utf16 or something else. The solution is to strip the encoding declaration as it's not needed anymore -- you already have a unicode string at your hand!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the solution is to do:

```
if isinstance(mystring, unicode):
    mystring = mystring.encode("utf-8")
```

Seriously. Good job, lxml.

EDIT: It turns out that, in this instance, lxml **autodetects the encoding incorrectly**. It appears that I will have to manually search for and remove "charset" and "encoding" from the page.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is NOT reencoding the string. The encoding declaration inside the string can say something other than UTF8. Don't blindly re-encode to utf8 and expect it to work all the time.

The solution is to just strip the encoding declaration. You already have an unicode string at hand, it's not needed anymore!

```
# this is from lxml/apihelpers.pxi
RE_XML_ENCODING = re.compile(
    ur'^(<\?xml[^>]+)\s+encoding\s*=\s*["\'][^"\']*["\'](\s*\?>|)', re.U)

RE_XML_ENCODING.sub("", broken_xml_string, count=1)
```

The worst case (where no xml encoding declaration is found) time complexity here is O(n), which is quite bad (but still better than blindly encoding to binary) so I'm open to suggestions here.

PS: Some interesting analyses of xml encoding problem:

[default encoding for XML is UTF-8 or UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302544/default-encoding-for-xml-is-utf-8-or-utf-16)

[How default is the default encoding (UTF-8) in the XML Declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361909/how-default-is-the-default-encoding-utf-8-in-the-xml-declaration)

Comment: If you give match operators like + and * a limit, replacing them with {,100}, the worst-case complexity for a long string is a lot less than O(the entire string length). The odds of hitting the worst case do seem pretty small, however!

Answer (score 0):

I had an existing implementation and I needed to have the tree.
I also had a nbsp; issue in a meta tag. Setting resolve_entities to false fixed that issue.

```py
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    response = opener.open(url['url'])
    raw_page = response.read()
    response.close()
    parsed_page = raw_page.replace(b'encoding="UTF-8"',b'')
    parsed_page = StringIO(parsed_page.decode('ASCII'))
    parser = ET.XMLParser(resolve_entities = False, encoding="ASCII")
    tree = ET.parse(parsed_page, parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
```