# default encoding for XML is UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

[OpenTag FAQ](http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm#enc_default) states:

> If no encoding declaration is present
>   in the XML document (and no external
>   encoding declaration mechanism such as
>   the HTTP header is available), the
>   assumed encoding of an XML document
>   depends on the presence of the
>   Byte-Order-Mark (BOM).
>
> The BOM is a Unicode special marker
>   placed at the top of the file that
>   indicate its encoding. The BOM is
>   optional for UTF-8.
>
> ```
> First bytes        Encoding assumed
> -----------------------------------------
> EF BB BF           UTF-8
> FE FF              UTF-16 (big-endian)
> FF FE              UTF-16 (little-endian)
> 00 00 FE FF        UTF-32 (big-endian)
> FF FE 00 00        UTF-32 (little-endian)
> None of the above  UTF-8
> ```

Is there a *dumbed-down* explanation of the above paragraph?

Comment: The explanation you're looking for is in the table below that paragraph...

Comment: @deceze of course i've read that part too! but i couldn't copy paste tables into the question could i?

Comment: I copy and pasted the table into your question. :o)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: This question, of course, is not an XSLT question.

Comment: It's worth noting not just where this is specified in the OpenTag FAQ, but also in the XML standard:  [4.3.3 Character Encoding in Entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding).  There it sounds like the auto-detected encodings only have to support UTF-8 and UTF-16, whereas the table in this question also mentioned UTF-32.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Either you have to use a line like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
```

to specify which encoding is used. If the encoding is not specified, a [Byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) can be present. If a BOM for either UTF-16 or UTF-32 is present, that encoding is used. Otherwise UTF-8 is the encoding. (The BOM for UTF-8 is optional)

**Edit**

The BOM is an invisible character. But there is no need to see it. Applications take care of it automatically. When you use windows notepad, you can select the encoding when you save the file. Notepad will automatically insert the BOM at the start of the file. When you later reopen the file, notepad will recognise the BOM and use the proper encoding to read the file. There is no need for you to ever modify the BOM, if you would do so, characters can get a different meaning, so the text will not be the same.

I will try to explain with an example. Consider a text file, with just the characters "test". Default notepad will use ANSI encoding, the text file will look like this when you view it in [hex mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump):

```
C:\>C:\gnuwin32\bin\hexdump -C test-ansi.txt
00000000  74 65 73 74                                       |test|
00000004
```

(as you see, I am using hexdump from gnuwin32, but you can also use an hex editor like [Frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) to see this.

There is no BOM in front of this file. It would not be possible, because the character which is used for the BOM does not exist in ANSI encoding. (Because there is not BOM, editors which don't support ANSI encoding, would treat this file as UTF-8).

when I now save the file like utf8, you will see 3 extra bytes (the BOM) in front of "test":

```
C:\>C:\gnuwin32\bin\hexdump -C test-utf8.txt
00000000  ef bb bf 74 65 73 74                              |ï»¿test|
00000007
```

(if you would open this file with a text editor which does not support utf-8, you would actually see those characters "ï»¿")

Notepad can also save the file as unicode, this means UTF-16 little-endian (UTF-16LE):

```
C:\>C:\gnuwin32\bin\hexdump -C test-unicode.txt
00000000  ff fe 74 00 65 00 73 00  74 00                    |ÿþt.e.s.t.|
0000000a
```

And here is the version saved as unicode (big endian) (UTF-16BE):

```
C:\>C:\gnuwin32\bin\hexdump -C test-unicode-big-endian.txt
00000000  fe ff 00 74 00 65 00 73  00 74                    |þÿ.t.e.s.t|
0000000a
```

Now consider a text file with the 4 chinese characters "琀攀猀琀". When I save that as  unicode (big endian), the result looks like this:

```
C:\>C:\gnuwin32\bin\hexdump -C test2-unicode-big-endian.txt
00000000  fe ff 74 00 65 00 73 00  74 00                    |þÿt.e.s.t.|
0000000a
```

As you see, the word "test" in UTF-16LE is stored the same way as the word "琀攀猀琀" in UTF-16BE. But because the BOM if stored different, you can see whether the file contains "test" or "琀攀猀琀". Without a BOM you would have to guess.

Comment: in case i've understood the wikipedia article wrongly.. it means that the encoding of the first character "<" decides it all right?

Comment: No, there is an invisible extra character in front of the first `<`. That character is chosen in a way that it never can be misinterpreted. So if you use an hex editor to look at the file, you will see the codes, and you can determine than what encoding is used in the rest of the file.

Comment: @Wimmel: A BOM is not mandatory -- so your previous comment isn't entirely true.

Comment: @Wimmel . but how do we alter what this `invisible extra character` is? I often use notepad.. so does it mean that there is no such BOM?

Comment: @Pacerier: I modified my answer explaining the BOM a little better. But please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: @Wimmel cool that's brilliant. Btw just a quick check: if i edit the `fe ff` to an unrecognizable BOM, say `ab cd` then now if i open the file he will think its ASCII encoded?

Comment: I just tried, it looks like notepad tries to guess the encoding. So it does not follow the rules explained on the opentag website. Notepad will display `ab cd` as an additional character. And if you then save without modifying, a BOM is inserted again, so the file will contain `ff fe ab cd ....`