# Able to de-serialize a xml document but cannot serialize to the same document

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, .net-4.5

I am able to de-serialize a xml document to an object using XMLDeserialization. But, i am stuck up when trying to serialize an object to a xml document because of XMLElement!

any ideas is much appreciated!

EDIT:
**I know its possible to construct this xml using XmlDocument or XDoc, but i have to use the existing class to perform serialization.**

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                    <DietPlan>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Fruit>Apple</Fruit>
                            <Fruit>Peach</Fruit>
                    </DietPlan>";

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
    public class TestData
    {
        [XmlAnyElement]
        public List<XmlElement> Fruits { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Deserialize()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestData));
        var obj = (TestData)xs.Deserialize(ms);

    }

    public static void Serialize()
    {
        var fruitList = new List<string> { "fig", "Apple", "Peach", };
        var testData = new TestData();

        //How to populate testData with fruitlist ? (Because it is a list of xmlElements!)

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a list of XmlElement in the strong-typed object?

Comment: this is just an example, but the real-use case is huge and different. I just had to know how I can use the existing TestData class for serialization!

Comment: @downvoter: care to comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not possible to modify the existing class and you don't want to use `XMLDocument`, `XDocument`, etc to explicitly produce the XML, then here are 2 main techniques you can use:

- create a companion class which has the correct XML attributes and types on it which you use just for serialization...this means you have to copy the data from your original class type into the new one, then serialize the new class
- use your original class and create `XmlElements` by using a dummy `XmlDocument`

This example shows both techniques in operation.

Also note how the `MemoryStream` uses a `StreamWriter` so that the XML gets written out explicitly as UTF-8 (the `encoding="UTF-8"` gets put in for you).

See [default encoding for XML is UTF-8 or UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302544/default-encoding-for-xml-is-utf-8-or-utf-16) ... for the different ways you might want to encode your XML.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
    public class TestData
    {
        [XmlAnyElement]
        public List<XmlElement> Fruits { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
    public class TestDataForSerialization
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fruit")]
        public List<string> Fruits { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                    <DietPlan>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Fruit>Apple</Fruit>
                            <Fruit>Peach</Fruit>
                    </DietPlan>";

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));

            TestData testdata1 = DeserializeFromStream<TestData>(ms);
            TestDataForSerialization testdata2 = DeserializeFromStream<TestDataForSerialization>(ms);
            TestData testdata3 = new TestData()
            {
                Fruits = new List<XmlElement>
                {
                    GetFruitElement("fig"),
                    GetFruitElement("Apple"),
                    GetFruitElement("Peach")
                }
            };
            TestDataForSerialization testdata4 = new TestDataForSerialization()
            {
                Fruits = new List<string> { "fig", "Apple", "Peach" }
            };
            TestDataForSerialization testdata5 = Convert(testdata1);

            MemoryStream msserialized1 = SerializeToStream<TestData>(testdata1);
            MemoryStream msserialized2 = SerializeToStream<TestDataForSerialization>(testdata2);
            MemoryStream msserialized3 = SerializeToStream<TestData>(testdata3);
            MemoryStream msserialized4 = SerializeToStream<TestDataForSerialization>(testdata4);
            MemoryStream msserialized5 = SerializeToStream(testdata5);

            string xml1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msserialized1.ToArray());
            string xml2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msserialized2.ToArray());
            string xml3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msserialized3.ToArray());
            string xml4 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msserialized4.ToArray());
            string xml5 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msserialized5.ToArray());

            TestData testdata_deserialized1 = DeserializeFromStream<TestData>(msserialized1);
            TestData testdata_deserialized2 = DeserializeFromStream<TestData>(msserialized2);
            TestData testdata_deserialized3 = DeserializeFromStream<TestData>(msserialized3);
            TestData testdata_deserialized4 = DeserializeFromStream<TestData>(msserialized4);
            TestData testdata_deserialized5 = DeserializeFromStream<TestData>(msserialized5);

            TestData testdata_deserialized6 = DeserializeFromString<TestData>(xml1);
            TestData testdata_deserialized7 = DeserializeFromString<TestData>(xml2);
            TestData testdata_deserialized8 = DeserializeFromString<TestData>(xml3);
            TestData testdata_deserialized9 = DeserializeFromString<TestData>(xml4);
            TestData testdata_deserialized10 = DeserializeFromString<TestData>(xml5);
        }

        public static XmlElement GetFruitElement(string fruit)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<Fruit>" + fruit + "</Fruit>");
            return doc.DocumentElement;
        }

        public static TestDataForSerialization Convert(TestData testdata)
        {
            TestDataForSerialization testdata_toserialize = new TestDataForSerialization();
            List<string> fruits = new List<string>();
            foreach (XmlElement el in testdata.Fruits)
            {
                fruits.Add(el.InnerText);
            }
            testdata_toserialize.Fruits = fruits;

            return testdata_toserialize;
        }

        public static T DeserializeFromStream<T>(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var obj = (T)xs.Deserialize(ms);

            return obj;
        }

        public static T DeserializeFromString<T>(string xml)
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestData));
            var sr = new StringReader(xml);
            var obj = (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);

            return obj;
        }

        public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream<T>(T testdata)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms); // you need to use one of these to get UTF8 output
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xs.Serialize(sw, testdata);

            return ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Colinsmith.. But, the problem is that we have the TestData class, tested and working great. It is also not a simple one. So, I need to be able to use the same class for serialization without modifying the existing one!

Comment: Thanks @Colinsmith. Exactly what i was looking out for! The dummy xmldocument to return a xmlElement is what the clue is!