# how to define encoding of a Base64 encoded string in java

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons

I received an XML file with a PDF Attachment in it encoded as `Base64` string. I am trying to generate a `PDF` file out of it. Following code works well:

```
String base64encodedPdf =" ....   ";
byte[] imgBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64encodedPdf);
IOUtils.write(imgBytes, new FileOutputStream("C:\\\\test.pdf"));
```

Problem arises when attachment data is too big to copy to editor directly, thought I can copy it to a text file and read file and convert to `String`. This is how I do it:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(file, encoding)
```

I am curious **what** encoding shall I specify... `UTF-8`, `UTF-16` and **why?**

**EDIT:**

This is the meta-information available to me

```
<AttachmentType tc="1">Document</AttachmentType>
<MimeType>application/pdf</MimeType>
<TransferEncodingTypeString>Base64</TransferEncodingTypeString>
<TransferEncodingTypeTC tc="4">Base64</TransferEncodingTypeTC>
```

Comment: Well what encoding has the text been stored in? We can't possibly know that - hopefully you do...

Comment: that's a good question.... I added to question what meta information I have available

Comment: Base64 is used to encode "binary" data.  Thus, when you decode it, and go to write the file to disk, you want to write the exact binary result, not some character encoding.  It's not character data.

Comment: @HotLicks sorry didn't follow you. What change are you suggesting

Comment: The only way to convert a PDF to a valid text file is with a PDF to text converter.

Comment: Of course, if you just want to look at the Base64 encoded data that's plain ASCII, and any ASCII or UTF8 encoding will be fine.  But a Base64-encoded file isn't much to look at.

Comment: @HotLicks my intent of copying Base64 encoded data to a file is just to read that file into code to generate PDF

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302544/default-encoding-for-xml-is-utf-8-or-utf-16) for how to determine what encoding your XML document is in. It'll most likely be UTF-8 but it could be something else depending on the BOM and the XML prolog.

Comment: @dcsohl cool.... this answer correctly points me. My XML prolog defines encoding. Thank you very much.

Comment: For pure Base64 it doesn't matter.  As I said, use ASCII or UTF8.  You confuse things by talking of converting "it" to string, without being clear whether you're talking about the encoded Base64 or the decoded PDF.  The former is a limited ASCII character set.  The latter is "pure binary" and has no "character set" associated with the file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what encoding you used when writing into the text file. Java text-related IO classes such as PrintWriter has a constructor that allows you to explicitly define the encoding, eg:

```
new PrintWriter("foo.txt", "UTF-8");
```

If you don't do so, it will use the default encoding which might vary depending on platform / JVM setting. You check your platform's default encoding using

```
Charset.defaultCharset()
```

But it's a good practice to always explicitly specify your intended encoding when writing to a file