# Matching XML Comments with awk

Tags: xml, regex, bash, unicode, awk

Sorry in advance for my English :(

I'm currently working on a "bash script" that applies a treatment for each xml comments.
It remains me, 2 "strange" problems without solution oO !

> *So... before, I'm going crazy* (*regex quoted* / *unquoted* / *slashed* / *invar... my madness ^^). I'm come here to get help :D*

I've tried several pattern but I've failed to find a pattern that match all cases...
First all, I've collect the required informations for my regex here: [XML Comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments).

> [15]      Comment    ::=      '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
>
> > [2]      Char       ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

I've "translate" this by:

> `xmlSpaceCharSet=" \r\n\t"`
>
> `xmlCharCharSet0="$xmlSpaceCharSet\x21-\x218F\\\\\\\x2C00-\\\\\\\xD7FF\\\\\\\xE000-\\\\\\\xFFFD\\\\\\\x10000-\\\\\\\x10FFFF"`
>
> `xmlCharCharSet1="$xmlSpaceCharSet\x21-\xD7FF\\\\\\\xE000-\\\\\\\xFFFD\\\\\\\x10000-\\\\\\\x10FFFF"`
>
> `xmlCommentPattern="<!--[^-][$xmlCharCharSet]*-->"`
>
> *Firstly, after some test, I've find a way to define range with unicode characters without awk failure with `\\\\\\\x<hex_val>`. But some range work with only one `\`, but doesn't work with `\\\\\\\`. Moreover, when range must start with one `\` like this: `\x21`, no need to escape the end like this: `\\\\\\\xD7FF`. And finally (facepalm), impossible to define range like this: `\xFF-\\\\\\\xFFFF`...*

Voodoo #1:

> test.xml:
> `<!-- Unicode XML Comments-[©╔ΘϘϖ] -->`
>
> test.sh:
> `echo "$(<$1)" | awk -v regexPattern="$xmlCommentPattern" '$0 ~ regexPattern'`
>
> With **xmlCharCharSet0 or xmlCharCharSet1** same result, **no match except without "╔ΘϘϖ" characters, the "©" is matched**...

Voodoo #2:

> test.xml:
>
> `<!-- Unicode XML Comments`
>
> `MultiLine`
>
> `-->`
>
> test.sh:
> `echo "$(<$1)" | awk -v regexPattern="$xmlCommentPattern" '$0 ~ regexPattern'`
>
> With **xmlCharCharSet0 or xmlCharCharSet1** same result, **no match except without \n**...

So if someone can help me, a solution, some informations... :) I'm going crazy ! ^^ =P

A header example that I need to find & check:

> `<!--`
>
> `User: all alpha format (latin, chinese, japan, ...)`
>
> `Date: all date/time format`
>
> `Last Revision: all date/time format`
>
> `Revision Code: [guid]`
>
> `-->`

Thank you for everything !

Comment: `<!--` may be present multiple times in a single line, and the 90th `<!--` may be last on the line, meaning you need to parse until the next `-->`. Because this must be done character by character, I'd say you're using the wrong tool for this job. Parsing markup should be done with an appropriate markup parser, not a simple text processing language, though awk is obviously not simple in itself.

Comment: It's sure ! But I need only the longest match, and it doesn't prohibit to matching new line in awk regex... And it's right if I wanted parse an xml file, but I just want check & find a header which is contained in xml comment tag. (I've updated my post with an example).

Comment: +1 for the most ambitious use of awk regex I've ever seen. Did  you look at http://home.vrweb.de/~juergen.kahrs/gawk/XML/ ? (I hope this is still a live link, else look for xgawk on the web. ). Finally did you search here on xmlstarlet. Good luck.

Comment: lol ty ^^ ;p Unfortunately, my solution must be without additional binary... only scripts =/

Comment: In `xmlCommentPattern="<!--[^-][$xmlCharCharSet]*-->"` what is `$xmlCharCharSet`? (You define `$xmlCharCharSet0` and `$xmlCharCharSet1`, but I cannot see that you have defined `$xmlCharCharSet`..)

Comment: What is the purpose of the six backslashes `\\\\\\`  in your regex patterns?

Comment: I've tried the both char set. And for the backslashes... it's the only way than I've can be found for skip awk issues...

Comment: Ok, I see.. What encoding do you assume for the XML file? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302544/default-encoding-for-xml-is-utf-8-or-utf-16

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure and I can't verify... "holidays oO" ^^ but i think it's UTF-8 why ? The only thing that I know it's than xml files can contains multi alpha(latin, chinese, russia, japan, greek... etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
awk -f c.awk test.xml
```

where `c.awk` is:

```
{
    line=line $0 RS
}
END {
    regex="<!--(.|(.?(-[^>]|[^-][^>]|[^-]>)*))->"
    while (match(line,regex)) {
        print ++i ": \"" substr(line,RSTART,RLENGTH) "\""
        line=substr(line,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
```

and `test.xml` is you input file.

I tried it with this file:

```
<!-- Unicode XML Comments-[©╔ΘϘϖ] -->
<!-- Unicode XML Comments

MultiLine

-->
aa


    <!--

    User: all alpha format (latin, chinese, japan, ...)

    Date: all date/time format

    Last Revision: all date/time format

    Revision Code: [guid]

    -->
```

with output:

```
1: "<!-- Unicode XML Comments-[©╔ΘϘϖ] -->"
2: "<!-- Unicode XML Comments

MultiLine

-->"
3: "<!--

    User: all alpha format (latin, chinese, japan, ...)

    Date: all date/time format

    Last Revision: all date/time format

    Revision Code: [guid]

    -->"
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm currently in test.... but for now no print for me :( I'm work on cygwin for my test... maybe it's that...

Comment: Lol... stupid... I've been copy ur output in XML... (facepalm)... So IT'S WORK !!!!!!!!! TY !!!!!!! ^^ U save me of tedious job ^^

Answer (score 2):

Line editors like awk and sed are poor choices for processing XML. I would recommend using [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), which can use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expressions to parse XML documents.

## Example

### data.xml

```
<data>
  <!--
  ==================
  First row
  Mulit-line comment
  ==================
  -->
  <row>
    <col1>one</col1>
    <col2>two</col2>
    <col3>three</col3>
  </row>
  <!--
  ==================
  Second row
  Mulit-line comment
  ==================
  -->
  <row>
    <col1>une</col1>
    <col2>duex</col2>
    <col3>trois</col3>
  </row>
</data>
```

### Retrieving comments

Use Xpath expression to retrieve the first comment:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "/data/comment()[1]" data.xml
<!--
  ==================
  First row
  Mulit-line comment
  ==================
  -->
```

Same goes for the second comment

```
$ xmllint --xpath "/data/comment()[2]" data.xml
<!--
  ==================
  Second row
  Mulit-line comment
  ==================
  -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... but like I've been already said unfortunately, my solution must be without additional binary... only scripts =/ But nice way to parse XML !

Comment: @user3134484 Awk is an additional binary :-) This is what I said at the beginning, doing this in bash sucks. Before dismissing xmllint check if it's already installed on your system (Installed by default on Ubuntu).

Comment: Sure it's an additional binary. But installed on AIX Systems ;) Not the case for xmllint i'm think. And it's sure not the case for server installed since 10 years.... I don't try to complicate my problem... I've just no choice.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Unlike sed, awk is not a "line editor". Awk works on records. By default a record is one line but it can be any multi-line or partial-line block of text you care to define.

Answer (score 0):

After new test, I could match new line only with one bracket range. If I add some chars before or after the bracket, the regex not match the new lines... oO
No progress for unicode characters...

Pattern used for match new line: "[a-zA-Z0-9\n]+".