# Can´t show UTF-8 encoding in generated XML by Apache Jena

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, jena

I want that Apache Jena generates an XML with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

My code:

```
RDFWriter writer = myJenaModel.getWriter("RDF/XML-ABBREV");
writer.setProperty("showXmlDeclaration", "true");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
writer.write(myJenaModel, osw, null);
```

only generates

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

But, if I change

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
```

to

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "ISO-8859-1");
```

it generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

as expected.

I tried to follow the instruction in [Jena documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdfxml_howto.html), but had no success.

Does anyone know how can I make Jena generate my RDF/XML with the UTF-8 encoding declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`encoding="UTF-8"` is the default for XML so it is not necessary.

Comment: First sentence on a very expensive course on XML by DataSim: XML is just ASCII. No it isn't; it's UTF-8.

Comment: [Non-spec citation](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp) as supporting evidence. UTF-8 is default.

Comment: See [default encoding for XML is UTF-8 or UTF-16?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6302544/1281433) for an discussion about how encoding is determined when there's no `encoding=…` declaration, and [4.3.3 Character Encoding in Entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding) in the XML standard for more about this behavior.

Comment: @AndyS With respect to the my previous comment, if the encoding is UTF-16, the document can begin with a BOM, and the text declaration could still be simply `<?xml version="1.0"?>` (following the BOM). When writing in UTF-16, will Jena use the BOM and `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, or no BOM and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`, or BOM and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>`?