# Remove non Unicode characters from xml database with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

So I have a 9000 line xml database, saved as a txt, which I want to load in python, so I can do some formatting and remove unnecessary tags (I only need some of the tags, but there is a lot of unnecessary information) to make it readable. However, I am getting a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 608814: character maps to <undefined>`, which I assume means that the program ran into a non-Unicode character. I am quite positive that these characters are not important to the program (the data I am looking for is all plain text, with no special symbols), so how can I remove all of these from the txt file, when I can't read the file without getting the `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Comment: How are you trying to load/read it? And do you know what encoding it's in? Also, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I pasted the part of the XML database I needed into a txt, then I'm using .read().splitlines() to get a list, which I can then format using the function I wrote on a line by line basis.

Comment: copying and pasting can mess up character encodings, depending on what tools you're using. I'll post an answer showing how you can skip over this exception, but it'll be just masking the larger problem. Or, if you're opening the file with the wrong encodings, unnecessarily destroying information. I guess how much that matters depends on your situation.

Comment: I don't know what the database is encoded as. It's a large database of text messages, with MMS and emojis stripped already. I'm using python 3.4.2. As for tools, I opened the XML in sublime text 2, copied all, except for a few tags near the start that didn't contain text I needed. I don't know much about XML files though, so I don't know how I could fix the problems, or find out what encoding it's in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One crude workaround is to decode the bytes from the file yourself and specify the error handling. EG:

```
for line in somefile:
    uline = line.decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

That will turn the line into a Unicode object in which any non-ascii bytes have been dropped. This is not a generally recommended approach - ideally you'd want to process XML with a proper parser, or at least know your file's encoding and open it appropriately (the exact details depend on your Python version). But if you're entirely certain you only care about ascii characters this is a simple fallback.

Comment: How can I find the encoding?

Comment: @Bretsky if nobody told you up front, you can guess by where the file originated. Windows is likely to use `cp1252` for example.

Comment: A hard topic. I usually end up using a binary display program like `od -c` to show me exactly what bytes are in the file, then narrowing it down based on experience. In your shoes I'd try `open('somefile.txt', encoding='utf8')` - I think that's sublime's default.

Comment: I used a SMS backup app on my Android, which created an XML database. I just want the body of the texts, the date, and who sent it.

Comment: @Bretsky coming from Android then `utf-8` would indeed be a good guess.

Comment: Then why would there be undefined Unicode characters in the file?

Comment: Actually, hmm, docs say python 3 assumes utf8. Possibly things got mangled at some step. If all else fails, open the file in binary mode, read it all, decode into Unicode using a variant on my answer and then split into lines - 9000 lines is nothing. But that's kind of horrible.

Comment: It's not undefined Unicode characters, it's a byte sequence that the decoder can't make sense of. there should be a filename in the traceback that tells you what codec is trying to handle it (the one you opened the file with). Honestly, I'd probably go back to working directly with the XML in this case, if it's an android XML dump I expect it's easily parsed with even something like the built in xml libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that you're using `open()` function without specifying an explicit character encoding. `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is used in this case (e.g., `cp1252`). The error says that it is not an appropriate encoding for the input.

[An xml document may contain a declaration at the very begining that specifies the encoding used explicitly. Otherwise the encoding is defined by BOM or it is utf-8.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6302544/4279) If your copy-pasting and saving the file hasn't messed up the encoding and you don't see a line such as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>` then open the file using `utf-8`:

```
with open('input-xml-like.txt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
    ...
```

If the input is an actual XML then just pass it to an XML parser instead:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
```