# How default is the default encoding (UTF-8) in the XML Declaration?

Tags: xml, utf-8

I know that [the default encoding of XML is UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding). All XML consumers MUST and so on and so forth. So this is not just a question whether or not XML has a default encoding.

I also know that [the XML-Declarataion `<?xml version="1.0" ... ?>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) at the beginning of the document itself is optional. And that specifying the encoding therein is optional as well.

So I ask myself if the following two XML-Declarations are two expressions for the exact same thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

From my own current understanding I would say those are equivalent but I do not *know*. 
Has the equivalence of these two declarations been specified somewhere?

(Consider these two example lines being each the first line of an XML document, preceded by any (zero) bytes and being UTF-8 encoded)

Comment: _Fortunately_ UTF-8 is the default per sé. When reading an XML document and writing it in another encoding, mostly this attribute will be patched too. Entirely unproblematic, and I cannot imagine why one so often sees the encoding attribute. The version is important though; higher versions allow tag names like `<café>`.

Comment: I'm not asking this because I have a problem with character encoding here. I'm just wondering as those look same to me, if this is specified or not. So that it's possible to test my software for conformance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The Short Answer**

Under the very specific circumstances of a UTF-8 encoded document with no external encoding information (which I understand from the comments is what you're interested in), there is no difference between the two declarations.

The long answer is far more interesting though.

**What The Spec Says**

If you look at [Appendix F1 of the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing-no-ext-info), that explains the process that should be followed to determine the encoding when there is no external encoding information.

If the document is encoded as one of the UTF variants, the parser should be able to detect the encoding within the first 4 bytes, either from the Byte Order Mark, or the start of the XML declaration.

However, according to the spec, it should still read the encoding declaration.

> In cases above which do not require reading the encoding declaration to determine the encoding, section 4.3.3 still requires that the encoding declaration, if present, be read and that the encoding name be checked to match the actual encoding of the entity.

If they don't match, according to [section 4.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/XML/#charencoding):

> ...it is a fatal error for an entity including an encoding declaration to be presented to the XML processor in an encoding other than that named in the declaration

**Encoded UTF-16, Declared UTF-8**

Let's see what happens in reality when we create an XML document encoded as UTF-16 but with the encoding declaration set to UTF-8.

Opera, Firefox and Chrome all interpret the document as UTF-16, ignoring the encoding declaration. Internet Explorer (version 9 at least), displays a blank document, but no actual error.

So if you include a UTF-8 encoding declaration on your UTF-8 document and someone at a later stage converts it to UTF-16, it'll work in most browsers, but fail in IE (and, I assume, most Microsoft XML APIs). If you had left the encoding declaration off, you would have been fine.

Technically I think IE is the most accurate. The fact that it doesn't display an error as such might be explained by the fact that the error is occurring at the encoding level rather than the XML level. It is assumedly doing its best to interpret the UTF-16 characters as UTF-8, failing to find any characters that decode, and ending up passing on an empty character sequence to the XML parser.

**Encoded UTF-8, Declared Otherwise**

You might now think that Firefox, Chrome and Opera are just ignoring the encoding declaration altogether, but that's not always the case.

If you encode a document as UTF-8 (with a byte order marker so it's unmistakable as anything else), but set the encoding declaration to Latin1, all of the browsers will successfully decode the content as Latin1, ignoring the UTF-8 BOM.

Again this seems right to me. The fact that the BOM characters aren't valid in Latin1 just means they are silently dropped at the character decoding level.

This doesn't work for all declared encodings on a UTF-8 document though. If the declared encoding is UTF-16, we're back with Opera, Firefox and Chrome ignoring the declared encoding, while Internet Explorer returns a blank document.

Essentially, anything that makes IE return a blank document is going to make other browsers ignore the declared encoding.

**Other Inconsistencies**

It's also worth mentioning the importance of the Byte Order Mark. According to [section 4.3.3 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XML/#charencoding):

> Entities encoded in UTF-16 MUST [...] begin with the Byte Order Mark

However, if you try and read a UTF-16 encoded XML document without a BOM, most browsers will nevertheless accept it as valid. Only Firefox reports it as an XML Parsing Error.

**External Encoding Information**

Up to now, we've been considering what happens when there is no external encoding information, but, as others have mentioned, if the document is received via HTTP or enclosed in a MIME envelope of some sort, the encoding information from those sources should take preference over the document encoding.

Most of the details for the various XML MIME types are described in [RFC3023](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt). However, the reality is somewhat different from what is specified.

First of all, text/xml with an omitted charset parameter should use a charset of US-ASCII, but that requirement has almost always been ignored. Browsers will typically use the value of the XML encoding declaration, or default to UTF-8 if there is none.

Second, if there is a UTF-8 BOM on the document, and the XML encoding declaration is either UTF-8 or not included, the document will be interpreted as UTF-8, regardless of the charset used in the Content-Type.

The only time the encoding from the Content-Type seems to take precedence is when there is no BOM and an explicit charset is specified in the Content-Type.

In any event, there are no cases (involving Content-Type) where including a UTF-8 XML encoding declaration on a UTF-8 document is any different from not having an encoding declaration at all.

Comment: The spec does say in section 4.3.3 what should happen if the encodings don't match: "In the absence of information provided by an external transport protocol (e.g. HTTP or MIME), it is a fatal error for an entity including an encoding declaration to be presented to the XML processor in an encoding other than that named in the declaration [...]" And later: "It is a fatal error if an XML entity is determined (via default, encoding declaration, or higher-level protocol) to be in a certain encoding but contains byte sequences that are not legal in that encoding."

Answer (score 8):

*In isolation*, both are equivalent. You have already cited the relevant parts of the specifications which show that both declarations are equivalent.

However XML can have an envelope, such as the HTTP `Content-Type` header. [The W3C specifies](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php) that this envelope information has priority over any other declarations in the file.  So for example, if you are retrieving XML via http, you could potentially get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml

<root/>
```

In this case, the XML should be read as *ascii*, because the default charset for `text/*` mime types is ascii. This is why you should use `application/xml` mime types--these default to utf-8. The "application" prefix means that the relevant application specifications define things like default encoding. (I.e. the XML spec takes over.) With `text/*` mime types, the default is ascii and the `charset` parameter must be included in the mime type to change charset.

Here's another case:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=win-1252

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root/>
```

In this case, a conforming XML processor should read this file as `win-1252`, *not* `utf-8`.

Another case:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="win-1252"?>
<root/>
```

Here the encoding is `win-1252`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ascii

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="win-1252"?>
<root/>
```

Here the encoding is `ascii`.

Comment: Hmm, no envelope. E.g. just loading a binary string into DOMDocument (DOM Level3). But it looks like that for DOM those are not equivalent. But why then if no envelope as you write in your answer? Is there more than just the "envelope"?

Comment: I don't have enough context to understand your comment. The DOM trees should be equivalent. If you have an example where they are not, you should put that in your question.

Comment: You write they should be equivalent, however, I see at least one difference: The one has the encoding written in the XML declaration, the other not. To which part in the specs do you relate when you write they should be equivalent nevertheless? If you could write that, this would be super-cool because that is the piece I'm looking for. In the DOM this is the xmlEncoding property of the DOMDocument that is different.

Comment: That is not a standard property, and anyway it expresses *what the XML declaration said*. Encoding is something for the parser to know--once the DOM is generated all strings are Unicode or something else standard, *not* the bytes in the raw file. See the `encoding` and `actualEncoding` in DOM3 spec and follow links to XML Infoset spec.

Comment: In other words, once you have a DOM, the encoding of the original document doesn't matter. `encoding` is what the declaration said (like `standalone` or `version`) and `actualEncoding` is how the parser parsed it, but all the strings are already converted from the document encoding to native strings.

Comment: *"it expresses what the XML declaration said."* - which is actually what I ask about in the question. When an expression is saying something, I would say that an expression is working, an expression is expressing. So that expressing here is what I'm asking about. How default is that default encoding for that expression for the expressing of that expression. E.g. in just dumping XML out - which has been expressed an encoding in the input - is both UTF-8 but the output differs. So is this then predictable or could this qualify a flaw? Do both expressions statue equivalence or not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are two different DOM attributes as I said. One is data from the processing instruction, the other is from the parser. If the XML document does not have `encoding="...."` written in it, `DOMDocument.encoding` has no value, but `DOMDocument.actualEncoding` will have the encoding the parser used to parse the document. That's all that is occurring here. Remember that the XML spec is not DOM-centric, so you should not put much stock in exact DOM equality when comparing documents.

Comment: Perhaps you need to give us a more precise definition of "equivalent". In both of your original scenarios the parser will regard the document as utf-8-encoded. That seems "equivalent" to me. But the DOM will differ by one property value even though the trees are otherwise the same.

Comment: Yes, and I wonder why. Isn't the XML encoding by the specs UTF-8 in both cases?

Comment: Yes, but the DOM chose to distinguish between "`encoding` param in the xml declaration" and "encoding the parser used", since as you can see these may be different. The XML infoset (vs the DOM) does not contain the `encoding` param in the xml declaration and only contains "what the parser used" information. However both can have `standalone` and `version` have no value if there was no xml declaration. I'm not sure why this is so mind-blowing to you!

Comment: Ah okay, and do you know if that has consequences for the output? E.g. should I (apart from CDATA) replace every character higher than U+007F with numeric XML entities in node values? Is that defined, too somewhere? And why mindblowing, it's just I want to understand. Practically I can deal with both cases, but this is more a strict programming question I have, not for dirty but worky code, but to really understand it.

Comment: This has absolutely no consequences for output. Just as the XML parser parsed it successfully as UTF-8, the XML renderer will serialize a valid document properly. Your DOM library will probably have an option to serialize to a different encoding if you want and will add or modify the xml declaration automatically.

Comment: Okay, this is in one case I became aware. DOMdocument in PHP which is libxml based does make a difference here based on the input string (with or w/o encoding in XMLDecl) but for the output. Sole difference so far was document xmlEncoding property (NULL/"UTF-8"). I can change that by explicitly set the output to UTF-8 encoding (and also the XML encoding param) but I still wonder because I could not find this relation in the specs and really looked for it. So it's not different but same encoding. E.g. in comments, I see UTF-8 characters, in elements I see XML entities.

Comment: This is not an xml parsing issue (the xml was already parsed) but the vulgarities of your particular DOM library. Once again, `xmlEncoding` is not standard.

Comment: xmlEcoding is in DOM Level 3 IIRC. No idea if that qualifies as a standard or not, but we can just leave it out, I only used it to describe that this was one property I could manifest a difference on. Probably the problem is that this property is not well defined / non-standard. If it were, this would probably more clear also in the other direction. Just saying, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You're right, it's `xmlEncoding` and `inputEncoding`. Not sure now where I was reading that it was `encoding` and `actualEncoding`. You can see in the [infoset mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/infoset-mapping.html#DocumentMapping) that `xmlEncoding`/`encoding='...'` is not part of the XML infoset.

Comment: Anyway your nose I think was right that what I described is because of the library I used for that test. I think I let this settle for a bit and if I find a peaceful moment, I'll check the annotated XML specs. This could give a bit more insight. I leave a bounty for you two guys. Not a big one, just some little rep. It's quite a special interest question.

Comment: For the record, when the Content-Type is text/xml with no charset, the specs may say that the document should be read as us-ascii, but the reality is that nobody does that in practice. Too many things would break if those specs were followed to the letter.

Answer (score 5):

It would not be unreasonable for the second declaration to be rejected if it arrived at the start of a document that had already been detected as having a non-UTF-8 compatible encoding (such as UTF-16). However, given your statement that the document is UTF-8 encoded, there is no difference between [how they would be treated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing-no-ext-info).

An externally-specified encoding would take precedence in both cases; both documents would still be treated identically.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but I have two problem here: First the section you link is not normative. Second - and more important - you write about character encoding of the input string and guessing that. My question is not about that, it is about the XML-Encoding, the declared one. And in how far the missing declaration is not a missing declaration at all.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, they are the same. I'm writing about detecting encoding to provide more detail for a very similar case, even though it's more general than what you're asking. I think 4.3.3's normative "it is a fatal error for an entity including an encoding declaration to be presented to the XML processor in an encoding other than that named in the declaration, or for an entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding declaration to use an encoding other than UTF-8" confirms this.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding), UTF-8 is *not* the default encoding in an XML declaration. It is only the default encoding "for an entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding declaration". If a document is in UTF-16 and has a BOM, it may have an XML declaration without an encoding declaration or no XML declaration at all and still be valid XML.

Only for documents without a BOM, the two XML declarations you mentioned should be equivalent.

Comment: Which is why you find at the end of the question *"(Consider these two example lines being each the first line of an XML document, preceded by any (zero) bytes and being UTF-8 encoded)"* :)

Comment: No problem, this can just happen.