# XML encoding using R

Tags: r, xml, encoding

I have created an XML tree using the XML package in R, when saving using 'saveXML' the encoding argument is ignored.

here is an example

```
   xml1 <- xmlTree()
   xml1$addTag("Data","Hello World")

   saveXML(xml1,filepath, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

the result is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Data>Hello World</Data>
```

however I was expecting the top line to read:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I was reading `help` on `saveXML` and it seems `prefix` attribute can be used to add that information. Try `saveXML(xml1,filepath, prefix = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')`. Please read help to understand the explanation.

Comment: Maybe because UTF-8 is the default? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361909/how-default-is-the-default-encoding-utf-8-in-the-xml-declaration

Comment: Typo?  Your sample code says `ecoding = "UTF-8"` not `encoding = "UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

The `saveXML` function has a `prefix=` parameter that you can use to set the header

```
saveXML(xml1, filepath, prefix='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
```