# Is there an expected behaviour for XML files when the real encoding and the tag are inconsistent?

Tags: xml, encoding, tags, undefined-behavior

Well I know it's a question about unexpected behaviours. But I guess there are some habits.

And I really need to know what is your response when you are confronted to such situations?

```
    \ encoding | utf-8       | other utf   | latin-1
TAG  \         |-------------|-------------|-----------
utf-8          | consistent  | valid       | abnormal
other utf      | abnormal    | consistent  | abnormal
missing        | depends     | depends     | depends
```

Usually, I guess,

- when there is no clue, utf-8 is guessed and used... or maybe the current locale of the system?
- And when it is abnormal, an error must be catched.

Example:

```
NO BOM
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- rest of the file encoded is latin1 or utf32 -->
<!-- or anything else with a lots of é à è ù ç... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ambiguity.

- When a byte order mark (BOM) is present at the start of the file, then this counts.
- Otherwise, when there is **no** encoding information present in the XML declaration, then the file encoding is UTF-8 (also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361909/how-default-is-the-default-encoding-utf-8-in-the-xml-declaration)).
- When there **is** encoding information present in the XML declaration, then this counts.
- There is no case where encoding declaration does not match the actual file encoding, because strictly speaking, the file ceases to be XML in this case.

The last situation can only happen when XML is created or modified by inappropriate tools, e.g. XML-unaware text editors, or by using string concatenation instead of an DOM API to create the file. Don't do that.

Comment: I think the most common cause of the mismatch situation is that the file was originally correctly encoded, but has been copied to a different encoding (transcoded) by a non-XML-aware process that didn't realise this would make the encoding inconsistent with the XML declaration.